# Modify script to read from file to try URL in list

Tags: python, bash, wget

I could use some help.  I've got this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import os
showname="Offsides"
station="http://myurl.com"
timestr = time.strftime("%B_%d_%Y-%H%M%p_%A")
directory = "/mnt/data/data/radio/current/"
filename = directory + showname +"_" + timestr + ".mp4"
command= "-q -O " + filename + " " + station +" &"
os.system("wget " + command)

#Record for an hour then kill this process based on grep for filename
time.sleep(3600)
pid=os.system("ps -ef | grep wget | grep -vi grep | grep " + filename + " | awk '{print $2}'| head -1")
os.system("kill -9 " + str(pid))
```

This records a streaming radio station for one hour and then kills the process.  I've noticed recently that some of my recordings are failing due to a station being unavailable (404 error).  The program is available on multiple URLS.  I would like to make this more robust.

I have a file (stations.txt) that has a list of URLS one per line.  What I would like to do is modify my script so that it tries the first in the list, sends the wget command to retrieve it, waits a second or two and then checks to see if the file (variable 'filename' from above) is growing.  If the file is not growing, then it would try the next URL.  This should help in missing these recordings.

I'm a novice with all this and would appreciate any help that you might be able to provide.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, and use something like the `requests` library instead of running an external process just to fetch a URL.

Comment: What you have now would be much simpler as a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a for loop statement after opening the file containing the URLs.
Please refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects for basic file opening structure.

```
#open file
f = open("your_file")
try:
    for line in f:
        #line contains urls from file
        print line
        station=line
        # continue with what ever you want to do
finally:
    f.close()
```